# Kendo Grid - In Firefox triggering an alert in the save event causes a page reload

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to know if anyone has seen this. I have a kendo grid and in the save event, I want to do some validation. Basically to make sure that the new values difference between the old is less than or equal to the balance.

So if it is greater than the balance, I trigger an alert and preventDefault. However displaying an alert causes the page to reload in FireFox.

Here is my grid:

```
$("#gridOpenInvoices").kendoGrid({
        autoBind: false,
        dataSource: openInvoicesData,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: false,
        navigatable: true,
        toolbar: [{name:"save",
                   text:strings.ApplyUpdates},
                  {name: "SplitPayment",
                   text: strings.SplitPayment},
                  {name: "PaidOut",
                   text: strings.PaidOut},
                  {name: "CreateCredit",
                   text: strings.CreditBalance},
                  {name: "UndoAllocation",
                   text: strings.UndoAllocation}],
        columns: [
            {
                field: "CustomerName",
                title: strings.AccountName,
                hidden: true
            },
            {
              field: "OpenTransactionId",
              title: strings.OpenTransaction,
              width:90
            },
            {
              field: "InvoiceNumber"  ,
              title: strings.InvoiceNumber,
              width:65
            },
            {
                field: "GrossSales",
                title: strings.OriginalAmount,
                width: 75,
                format: "{0:c}",
                decimals: 2,
                min: 1,
                value: 0

            },
            {
                field: "Balance",
                title: strings.TransBalance,
                width: 75,
                format: "{0:c}",
                decimals: 2,
                min: 1,
                value: 0

            },
            {
                field: "Date",
                title: strings.Date,
                width:75,
                format: "{0:MM/dd/yy}"

            },
            {
                field: "Age",
                title: strings.Age,
                width:55

            },
            {
                field: "CheckNumber",
                title: strings.CheckNumber,
                width:85
            },
            {
                title: strings.ApplyPayment,
                width:75,
                template: "<input class='k-chk-applied chkbox' type='checkbox' data-bind='source: IsApplied' name='IsApplied' #= IsApplied ? 'checked' : ''#/>",
                attributes:{"class":"tdIsApplied"}
            },
            {
                field:"AppliedAmount",
                title: strings.AppliedAmount,
                format: "{0:c}",
                width: 95,
                attributes: {"class" : "tdAppliedAmount"}
            }],
save: function(e) {
    var model = e.model;
    if (e.values.AppliedAmount != null) {
        var remainingBalance = context.getRemainingBalance();
        var difference = e.values.AppliedAmount - model.AppliedAmount;
        if (remainingBalance >= difference) {
            var balanceCopy = model.BalanceCopy;
            model.Balance = model.GrossSales - e.values.AppliedAmount;
            model.BalanceCopy = model.GrossSales - e.values.AppliedAmount;

            if (model.Balance == 0 && model.IsUncollected) {
                model.IsUncollected = false;
                context.UpdateBalance(balanceCopy, 0, true);
            }
            context.UpdateBalance(model.AppliedAmount, e.values.AppliedAmount, true);
            this.refresh();
            context.showButtons();
        } 
        else {
            alert("The applied amount exceeds the remaining balance");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}, editable:"incell"});
```

This seems to be only happening when you edit the applied amount and hit enter to commit. Any idea of why this is happening?

Comment: I guess it seems that I am the only one seeing this. Just to add, when the save event is fired and no alert in displayed, everything goes fine. The crazy part with firefox is if I even place a debugger in the save event and enter an amount in the appliedAmount field and hit the enter key, the page reloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is fairly simple: Do not use an alert.

I do have the same problem in some events in kendoUI Widgets.
If you need to display something to the user, use kendoWindow with it's modal property set to true.

Alerts should only be used for debugging purposes, like console.log.

Comment: Ah I see. my assumption was the alert was actually using a kendoWindow. Thanks this worked.